# How to add Mapbox basemap to leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, tilemill

I am using the Leaflet example of mapping points from CSV. But I want to use my mapbox basemap.

https://github.com/perrygeo/leaflet-simple-csv

I am new to leaflet. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass Leaflet a URL to the map's TileJSON endpoint. Here's a basic template as well as some [more documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api-overview/) on Mapbox's API.

`http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/user.map-id/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

Comment: I've tried that but no luck. current config.js:
 
var baseUrl = 'http://otile{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg';
var baseAttribution = 'Data, imagery and map information provided by <a href="http://open.mapquest.co.uk" target="_blank">MapQuest</a>, <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> and contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/" target="_blank">CC-BY-SA</a>';
var subdomains = '1234';
var clusterOptions = {showCoverageOnHover: false, maxClusterRadius: 50};
var labelColumn = "Name";
var opacity = 1.0;

Comment: it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. do you want to replace `var baseURL` with a mapbox map? please edit and explicate your original post with these details so more developers can provide support.